# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP pls helpz

Tags: java, jsp, maven

I'm making a web application project using Maven. I've jsp file as `index.jsp`.

Here is `index.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%> 
<%@ page import="rajendra.arora.bitcoin.CoinbaseExample" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>My name is fooo.</p>
<%
    CoinbaseExample ce=new CoinbaseExample();
    out.println(ce.getHttp("https://api.coinbase.com/v1/account/balance", null));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I've `CoinbaseExample.java` file which looks something like:

```
package rajendra.arora.bitcoin;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import com.coinbase.api.Coinbase;
import com.coinbase.api.CoinbaseBuilder;

public class CoinbaseExample {

    static String API_KEY = "API_KEY";

    static String API_SECRET = "API_SECRET";

    public static String getHttp(String url, String body)
            throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        String nonce = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String message = nonce + url + (body != null ? body : "");

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(API_SECRET.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256"));
        String signature = new String(Hex.encodeHex(mac.doFinal(message.getBytes())));

        HttpRequestBase request;
        if (body == null || body.length() == 0)
            request = new HttpGet(url);
        else {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(body));
            request = post;
        }
        request.setHeader("ACCESS_KEY", API_KEY);
        request.setHeader("ACCESS_SIGNATURE", signature);
        request.setHeader("ACCESS_NONCE", nonce);

        Coinbase cb = new CoinbaseBuilder()
        .withApiKey(System.getenv(API_KEY), System.getenv(API_SECRET))
        .build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null)
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        return null;
    }

}
```

I've also inserted `dependency` into `pom.xml` like:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

After running my program it says:

```
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;D:\eclipse;;.
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:coinbase-java' did not find a matching property.
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:46 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:46 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2440 ms
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.0-RC5
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\raj\Documents\jsp projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\coinbase-java\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:51 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4557 ms
Dec 02, 2014 2:56:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/coinbase-java] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [32] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\raj\Documents\jsp projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\coinbase-java\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [32] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\raj\Documents\jsp projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\coinbase-java\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:467)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:606)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And my `index.jsp` says:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP.
```

***Please, help me :(***

***Surely, your help would be appreciated!!***

Comment: `The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory
`

Comment: Sorry.. don't get you .. pls help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the source on my tomcat 6/7 its working fine.
I got

```
My name is fooo.

{"error":"ACCESS_KEY not matched with a user"}
```

I guess the error is because I commented

```
//        Coinbase cb = new CoinbaseBuilder()
//        .withApiKey(System.getenv(API_KEY), System.getenv(API_SECRET))
//        .build();
```

Try Project>Clean... , and then Tomcat>Clean...